# How do I make a browser go to a website in the background using a Telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm coding my own Telegram bot using Python, and I want to make the bot go to a website by itself on the phone of all members of my group. I want to do this, because I want people to see the group rules which are on my website after joining the groupchat.

My code so far is:

```
import os
import telebot
import time
import threading

my_secret = os.environ['API_KEY']
bot = telebot.TeleBot(my_secret)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['Greet'])
def greet(message):

  # Opens browser and goes to website on browser in background
  pass

bot.polling()
```

How can I do it? I want to add the code in the command section, so that when I type a command, the bot goes to the website on the phones of group members.

Comment: “*I want to make the bot go to a website by itself on the phone of all members of my group.*” Meaning without explicit user consent…? I have to imagine such a feature is not possible when considering the implications from a security and UX perspective. Is your expectation that the “*bot*” is running on all the individual clients?

Comment: This is a bit too broad *and* vague for us to help you. Please take the [tour], see [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Aside, we’re not going to write all your code *for you* (a skeleton method with no implementation is not a [mre]).

Comment: Nope, you can't force the users' clients to show a given web page.

Comment: Is that really a bot or some consent-breaching machine? Just asking.

Comment: Related: *[Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)*